# Update specfic column of a specific row in datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid (ID `dgShowSearching`) in WPF and contains a button inside the same datagrid.

On click of button , I do some operations.

After operation performed I want to update two columns in the same row.

Column names are `Status` and `AddedRecords`

Column Indexes are `6` and `5`

How it can be done.

Below is code of button click

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 DataGrid grvRow = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(sender as UIElement);
 if (grvRow != null)
 {
     // SOME OPERATIONS PERFORMED
     // ................ 

     // Here I want to update two columns in the same row ??
     // DataGrid id is dgShowSearching 

 }
}

 public static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
        {
            UIElement parent = element;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
                if (correctlyTyped != null)
                {
                    return correctlyTyped;
                }
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: try `FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>` or `dgShowSearching.SelectedItem as DataGridRow`

Comment: I need to update the column after some BackgroudWorkerProcess

Comment: You can pass the row as state to the background worker using `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` method, and do your modifications once completed using `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.UserState` property which is an instance of DataGridRow you've passed earlier